# VBA loop logic needed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have got two lists to compare in Excel. This is a very long list and I need a excel function or vba code to do this. I have run out of ideas, hence turning to you:

```
**Old List**    
    A            Jersey City
                 London
    B            Banglore             
                 London
                 Stamford
    C            Hong Kong
                 Hyderabad
                 Singapore
**New List**    
    B       Banglore
            London
            Stamford
    C       Hyderabad
            Singapore
```

Names are in Column A and Locations in Column B

Logic Needed:

- Compare locations for each name
- If location in New List is different from Old list:e.g. 1) New locations added 2) Number of locations are still the same but these are new locations. Then highlight, or in next column say "new location"/ anything to identify that this is a change from Old list

Thanks and Regards
Varun

Comment: give us an excel screenshot of what you really have in your excel file and the structure as well as the column of the expected results. this would help a lot

Comment: I was trying that but says i Need 10 reputation to post an image. Any other way to post the sample list

Comment: Use a free image sharing site and edit your post with the link.

Comment: Hi Christmas007 ..Just edited post with help of Paddyd..Thanks Pad

Comment: so you are comparing old list with new list and what do you want in your RESULT list? on what criteria do you want to compare them? explain more

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes your Old List and New List are in seperate sheets.  You will need to edit the code to reflect the actual sheet name.  If finds all duplicate names and then checks to see if the city has changed.  If the city has changed it highlights the city on both the Old List AND the New List.

**EDIT: Haven't tested, but try something like this!  Finds matches of names, sets a given range of locations that associate with that name on both sheets, compares cells and highlights any cells that are not found in both ranges.  Keep in mind this only works for names that appear on both sheets.**

**EDIT 2: CODE UPDATED - Tested and working.**

```
Sub DupChange()

Dim CurRow, LastRow, DestRow, DestLast, ChkRow, DestChk As Long
Dim OldL, NewL As Worksheet
Dim ChkRng, DestRng As Range
Dim ChkCel, DestCel As Range

Set OldL = Sheets("Old List")
Set NewL = Sheets("New List")

LastRow = OldL.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DestLast = NewL.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow '(assuming you have a header in row 1)
    If Not OldL.Cells(CurRow, 1).Value = "" Then
        ChkRow = OldL.Cells(CurRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row - 1
        If ChkRow > LastRow Then
            ChkRow = LastRow
        Else
        End If
        Set ChkRng = OldL.Range("A" & CurRow & ":A" & ChkRow).Offset(0, 1)
        For DestRow = 2 To DestLast
            If OldL.Cells(CurRow, 1).Value = NewL.Cells(DestRow, 1).Value Then
                DestChk = NewL.Cells(DestRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row - 1
                If DestChk > DestLast Then
                    DestChk = DestLast
                Else
                End If
                Set DestRng = NewL.Range("A" & DestRow & ":A" & DestChk).Offset(0, 1)
                For Each ChkCel In ChkRng
                    If DestRng.Find(ChkCel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                        ChkCel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                    End If
                Next
                For Each DestCel In DestRng
                    If ChkRng.Find(DestCel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                        DestCel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                    End If
                Next
            Else
            End If
        Next DestRow
    Else
    End If
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying something on the same lines but the problem is that, if you look at the structure 1st Columns are Names and have empty cells, hence what happens is: Case a) Old List: Christmas007 has locations New Jersey and Banglore, New List: Varun Yadav has locations New York and Banglore. Code matches Banglore, which is wrong!!

Comment: You are saying that a person can have multiple locations?  And you need to check if any of those location changes are different?  That is considerably more challenging... :(

Comment: Yes thats correct, trust me if it was this simple, I would not have troubled you guys. One way it could work would be to 1st to copy names in blank cells and then use match or any comparison mechanism.

Comment: Shouldn't need to copy down.  I am working on something that selects the range and then identifies.

Comment: added Set OldL = Sheets("Old List")
Set NewL = Sheets("New List") but dies, at DestRng = Range("A" & DestRow & ":A" & DestChk).Offset(0, 1) with runtime error 91   .. :(

Comment: modified: Set DestRng = Range("A" & DestRow & ":A" & DestChk).Offset(0, 1)
but If DestRng.Find(ChkCel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then  .... is giving runtime 424..any ideas what to declare here?

Comment: Not sure I understood your last comment.  If you define both ranges using `Set` (my bad on syntax) then what is your error now?

Comment: Hey I updated the top post, with some real data. The code didn't work :(

Comment: Code is updated and I tested it to be working with your sample data above.

Answer (score 0):

A simple lookup would allow you to solve this problem.
Eg:

```
[C2] =OFFSET(Old_List!A:A;MATCH(B2;Old_List!B:B;0)-1;0;1;1)
```

will fill C2 with corresponding old name for location in B2.

```
[D2] =A2=C2
```

will fill D2 with `True` when old name is same as new, `False` otherwise and `#N/A` when name is new and is not found in old list.

Comment: One location let's say New York can be with Many managers. I need to do is use manager as unique pivot point and check the corresponding locations

Answer (score 0):

The basic architecture I would go with would be as follows:

Build a `Collection` with the name as `Key` and each `Item` being a `Collection` of locations with the `Key` being the location text and the `Item` being the `Range` (i.e. the cell) containing the location text.

Wrap the `Collection` in a `Class Module` and add a Property to set the list range.
In the Range setter, call a routine to build the `Collection`.

Then add a property to get the locations `Collection` for a particular name.

You can then make two instances of the `Class`, one called oldList and one called newList and make a very simple loop to compare them and manage the formatting of the location cells.